# Condition on $h^2-ab$ for deciding a conic

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

> Consider the conic represented by the general equation $$ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2gx+2fy+c=0$$

It is known that if it's discrminant, that is, $abc+2fgh-af^2-bg^2-ch^2>0$, then it represents

**1)** A parabola, if $h^2=ab$

**2)** An ellipse, if $h^2<ab$

**3)** A hyperbola, if $h^2>ab$

I want to prove the above claim. My attempt:

> Any two degree curve is either a pair of straight lines, a parabola , an ellipse (or a circle) or a hyperbola.
>
> We start by considering the equation of conic as a quadratic in $x$. Solving for $x$ yields $$x=\dfrac{-(hy+g)}{a} \pm \dfrac{1}{a}\sqrt{(h^2-ab)y^2+2(gh-af)y+g^2-ac}$$
>
> Now we want to find the conditions from above for it represents different conics. Suppose we want to find the condition of parabola. We know here $2$ things. There exists either a unique value of $x$ for a given $y$ (that is to say, it's vertex) or a unique value of $y$ for a given $x$, and secondly, parabola is an unbounded curve. So, what I am trying to do is to consider the graph of the quadratic $(h^2-ab)y^2+2(gh-af)y+g^2-ac$  and I want to prove somehow from here that $h^2=ab$ would result in a parabola along the lines I described, but till now I am unable to do so. Similarly, if it should be an ellipse, then since we know that ellipse is a bounded curve, somehow we need to prove that the graph of the quadratic equation $(h^2-ab)y^2+2(gh-af)y+g^2-ac=0$ would become a downward parabola with distinct real roots.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, if $h^2-ab>0$, $y$ is unbounded and the curve is open (hyperbola). It negative, it is bounded and closed (ellipse). If zero, $y$ is unbounded only on one side.

Comment: @LightYagami: is this how you thank ??? Don't blame me for you making the question that long.